# I Need Recommendations for a CPU upgrade. I Currently Have Intel I5 7400 3.0GHz

Tags: processor, gaming

I'm looking to spend up to $300. If the CPU upgrade requires a Motherboard upgrade thats okay, I want to be able to upgrade further in the future.

My Current Specs:

- Radeon rx 580
- MSI Bazooka 250m

Any Recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Caveat:* CPU upgrade alone, with original RAM, HDD/SSD and GPU, is unlikely to be worth the money or effort.

Comment: I disagree.  I upgraded my CPU from an i7 7th gen to 10th gen and it made lots of daily tasks faster.  Mainly startup, virus scanning, and decompression.